# Client of Azerothcore ask for 2 factors authentification, how can I disable it?

Tags: azerothcore

I did an installation of last version of azerothcore (with debian and docker) on a virtual machine and it worked fine (can do normal login). Then I followed the same steps on a real machine, but the client is asked for two-step authentication. (with a new ddbb and only one user added)
What could have happened?
Where are the settings for activate/deactivate this type of authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in that revision, you just need to update to the latest version again and it should be fine now.